# A* algorithm pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I found the pseudocode from wikipedia

```
function A*(start, goal)
    // The set of nodes already evaluated.
    closedSet := {}
    // The set of currently discovered nodes still to be evaluated.
    // Initially, only the start node is known.
    openSet := {start}
    // For each node, which node it can most efficiently be reached from.
    // If a node can be reached from many nodes, cameFrom will eventually contain the
    // most efficient previous step.
    cameFrom := the empty map

    // For each node, the cost of getting from the start node to that node.
    gScore := map with default value of Infinity
    // The cost of going from start to start is zero.
    gScore[start] := 0 
    // For each node, the total cost of getting from the start node to the goal
    // by passing by that node. That value is partly known, partly heuristic.
    fScore := map with default value of Infinity
    // For the first node, that value is completely heuristic.
    fScore[start] := heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

    while openSet is not empty
        current := the node in openSet having the lowest fScore[] value
        if current = goal
            return reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)

        openSet.Remove(current)
        closedSet.Add(current)
        for each neighbor of current
            if neighbor in closedSet
                continue        // Ignore the neighbor which is already evaluated.
            // The distance from start to a neighbor
            tentative_gScore := gScore[current] + dist_between(current, neighbor)
            if neighbor not in openSet  // Discover a new node
                openSet.Add(neighbor)
            else if tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]
                continue        // This is not a better path.

            // This path is the best until now. Record it!
            cameFrom[neighbor] := current
            gScore[neighbor] := tentative_gScore
            fScore[neighbor] := gScore[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)

    return failure

function reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)
    ....
```

But something I still don't understand, what is **heuristic_cost_estimate()**?
The pseudocode didn't show what the function is.
In my opinion it is other algorithm like dijkstra, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function will return a heuristic value which is used to make a decision. In A*, it's normally the shortest straight distance between the present node and the final one so that function seems to simply calculate the distance (straight, not using paths) between two given nodes.

Comment: So it's same to dist_between()?

Comment: Yes, it is. As Henry says, it should be any value below the real value (using the paths) but for a good performance, you should use the shortest distance between the nodes

Comment: It's not a "wrong" result, given you don't know the shortest path, you use this estimation to make decisions. Without the estimation (or returning 0 as Henry said) you would be blind and trying random nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The heuristic must give a lower bound of the real cost. It is important that the returned value is less or equal to the real minimal cost or the algorithm does not work correctly.

Any estimate that fulfills this requirement will work. Even the simplest choice to return 0 all the time works. However, the better the estimate the better the performance of the algorithm.